# How can I get the value from @QueryParam

Tags: jax-rs, http-status-code-404, resteasy

Basically what I'm trying to do is edit an entity that's stored in my db. For that I have a little method that is trying to access a paramater that's defined with `@PathParam`. My problem is that it comes back as `null`. Here is my method:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response edit(@PathParam("id") Long id, @QueryParam("myParam") String name)
{
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I`m using Postman to send the parameter to my server. My URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApplication/rest/users/1?myParam=test
```

How can I get the value from the parameter?

Comment: I got a 400 status code

Comment: @ffs if you are getting 404; it means that your path + Http Method combination doesn't exist. remember that your API is sporting only PUT method, make sure you selected PUT on post man. Please clarify your question : attach the screen capture of what you get on postman so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: I removed my other methods from the class and now it works...

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
public Response edit(@PathParam("id") Long id, @QueryParam("myParam") String myParam) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

This will work. The query param and variable name will get auto bind if they are similar.